# Goroutine to populate struct instance slice

Tags: go, goroutine

This is my first day using Go and I had a question about goroutines and appending to an instance's slice.

The idea is that each Truck would have a Cargo of length 1 containing an Item with name "Groceries". I almost have it, but for some reason it's losing the properties of the truck, and it seems to be terminating prematurely.

https://play.golang.org/p/f0uIy5qg8d

```html
package main

import "fmt"
import "time"

type Item struct {
   name string
}

type Truck struct{
   Cargo []Item
   name  string
}

func UnloadTrucks(ch chan *Truck){
    t := <- ch

    fmt.Printf("%s has %d items in cargo: %s\n", t.name, len(t.Cargo), t.Cargo[0].name)
    time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    return 
}

func main() {
     trucks := make([]Truck, 2)

     ch := make(chan *Truck)

     for i, t := range trucks{
         t.name = fmt.Sprintf("Truck %d", i + 1)

  fmt.Printf("Building %s\n", t.name)
     }



     for _, t := range trucks {
            go func(tr *Truck){
    itm := Item {}
                  itm.name = "Groceries"


                fmt.Printf("Loading %s", tr.name)
                  tr.Cargo = append(tr.Cargo, itm)
                  ch <- tr

            }(&t)
     }

     UnloadTrucks(ch)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is not that the truck's properties are "lost", but they're never set in the first place. This loop is your problem:

```
for i, t := range trucks {
    t.name = fmt.Sprintf("Truck %d", i + 1)
    fmt.Printf("Building %s\n", t.name)
}
```

Within this loop, `t` is a *copy* of the Truck object in the `trucks` slice. Any modification on this object will not affect the original truck. Instead, you can reference the original Truck object by using the index variable `i` to directly access the object in the `trucks` slice:

```
for i, _ := range trucks {
    trucks[i].name = fmt.Sprintf("Truck %d", i + 1)
    fmt.Printf("Building %s\n", trucks[i].name)
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that helped!

I've updated the code a bit, now it just fails with a deadlock.

https://play.golang.org/p/opogH_TxPt

Comment: Specifically: 
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!

goroutine 1 [chan receive]:
main.UnloadTrucks(0x104360c0, 0x193ce8)
 /tmp/sandbox736348381/main.go:17 +0x80
main.main()
 /tmp/sandbox736348381/main.go:52 +0x3c0

Comment: Ugh, having a bugger of a time getting around the deadlock. The updated playground: 

https://play.golang.org/p/tbRnoWvOCP

Trying to understand why range is hitting the channel cursor even after the loop has terminated.

Comment: You have a deadlock because you're reading from a channel in which no goroutine can write anymore (because all your goroutines apart from the main thread have already finished). You could add a timer for implementing a timeout or something similar; that might be an issue for a separate question, though.